# How can I get the unique id of an Object after overwriting its toString() method?

Tags: java

I can get the unique id like className@2345 of my object by calling its toString() method, but after I overwrite the toString() method, how can I get that unique id?

Comment: FOR CRYING OUT LOUD, IT'S NOT UNIQUE. (sorry)

Comment: True it is just a hash code and not unique indeed.  But in most cases I can use it to distinguish the objects.

Comment: "In most cases" simply defines probability, not something you typically rely on in software, unless you are writing code for gambling  ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call System.identityHashCode() and pass your object as parameter, then you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely

```
obj.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(obj))
```

Comment: Or just

public String identityString() {
  return super.toString();
}

?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one line toString() implementation that will also print the className@address, check out Apache Commons [ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString(java.lang.Object)). This will return a String in the format: className@address[field1=value1, field2=value2, ...]